# Here, is "Turning down" the same meaning as "if I turned down"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Here's the sentence from "how I met your mother"

> 1. I´d feel a little Stepford turning down a huge opportunity to chase some guy I´d only known 2 months

And here, does "turning down" mean "if I turned down"?

> 2. I´d feel a little Stepford **if** I turned down a huge opportunity to chase some guy I´d only known 2 months

So, #1 and #2 are the same meaning?

Comment: The actual sentence seems to be: "[I'd feel a little Stepford turning down a huge opportunity to chase some guy I'd only known two months](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/169824-Stepford)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences have the same meaning of how the speaker **would feel** if they **missed** an opportunity

> **turning down** a huge opportunity, I **would** feel a little Stepford
>   if I **turned down** a huge opportunity, I **would** feel a little Stepford

more of a difference would occur if

> I feel a little Stepford **turning down** a huge opportunity

which would place the feel as a result of an action